# Como unir consultas en sql server y escribir codigo en visual studio 2019?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

No tengo mucho conocimiento en como unir consultas, pero si me pueden apoyar se los agradeceria,
quiero mostrar la produccion por hora por un nuemero de parte, pero me gustaria que se muestre horizontalmente y ahorita me coloca hacia abajo el resultado este codigo lo hago en visual studio 2019 y base sql server 2020.

pongo codigo actual:

```
"Dim QProd As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '8:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '07:00' and '07:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                        "group BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd1 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '9:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '08:00' and '08:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                              "group BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd2 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '10:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '09:00' and '09:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                         "group BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd3 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '11:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '10:00' and '10:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                         "GROUP BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd4 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '12:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '11:00' and '11:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                        "GROUP BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd5 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '1:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '12:00' and '12:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                         "GROUP BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd6 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '2:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '13:00' and '13:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                         "GROUP BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd7 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '3:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '14:00' and '14:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'" &
                                         "GROUP BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd8 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '4:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '15:00' and '15:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                        "GROUP BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd9 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '5:00' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '16:00' and '16:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                        "GROUP BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        Dim QProd10 As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT detalle_piezas.confnumero as 'LINE', Contenedor.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', COUNT(Contenedor.nparnumero) As '5:06' " &
                                        "FROM Detalle_Piezas INNER JOIN Contenedor ON Detalle_Piezas.contnum = Contenedor.contnum WHERE Detalle_Piezas.confnumero Like '%GC701%'" &
                                        "and detalle_piezas.pdetfecha like '" & Me.lblfecha.Text & "' and detalle_piezas.pdethora between '17:00' and '17:59:59' and detalle_piezas.turnonum like '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' " &
                                        "GROUP BY Detalle_Piezas.confnumero,contenedor.nparnumero order by confnumero", MiConexion)
        QProd.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd1.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd2.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd3.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd4.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd5.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd6.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd7.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd8.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd9.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        QProd10.Fill(DSet_Piezas, "DePiezas")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DSet_Piezas.Tables("DePiezas")"
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hacia abajo.. te muestra registros... porque asi es como funcionan todos los motores de base de datos. Con todo lo que pusiste, va a ser muy dificil ayudarte... Tu query es enormeeeee.. que esperas que hagamos para ayudarte?? mira por favor [mcve]

Comment: No existe SQL Server 2020.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas no es unir las consultas sino combinarlas para hacer una sola. También necesitas parametrizar la consulta para evitar ser vulnerable a inyección de SQL.

Dejo un ejemplo de como quedaría la consulta.

```
SELECT dp.confnumero as 'LINE', 
       c.nparnumero As 'PART NUMBER', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '07:00' and '07:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As  '8:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '08:00' and '08:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As  '9:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '09:00' and '09:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As '10:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '10:00' and '10:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As '11:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '11:00' and '11:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As '12:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '12:00' and '12:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As  '1:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '13:00' and '13:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As  '2:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '14:00' and '14:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As  '3:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '15:00' and '15:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As  '4:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '16:00' and '16:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As  '5:00', 
       COUNT( CASE WHEN dp.pdethora between '17:00' and '17:59:59.997' THEN c.nparnumero ELSE NULL END) As  '6:00'
FROM Detalle_Piezas dp
INNER JOIN Contenedor c ON dp.contnum = c.contnum 
WHERE dp.confnumero LIKE '%GC701%'
AND   dp.pdetfecha  LIKE @Fecha --Esto debería usar igual en vez de LIKE porque es fecha y no cadena
AND   dp.turnonum   LIKE @TurnoNum
GROUP BY dp.confnumero,
        c.nparnumero 
ORDER BY confnumero;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis, me funciono a la perfeccion y una disculpa por no plantear la pregunta mas clara, pero esto es lo que estaba buscando.

Comment: @PabloJesusCastilleja, no olvides aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias y me funciono a la perfeccion, una disculpa por no plantear bien la pregunta pero si se acerto la gran ayuda.